# Missing operand error when filtering data

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I get this error when I try to filter data: `Server Error in '/' Application. Syntax error: Missing operand after ''%1%'' operator.`

This is the code that produces the problem:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (con = new OleDbConnection(@"PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + @"DATA SOURCE= C:\Users\ASAD\Docements\Student.accdb")) ;
}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string FilterExpression = string.Concat(DropDownList1.SelectedValue, "LIKE '%{0}%'"); 
    SqlDataSource1.FilterParameters.Clear();
    SqlDataSource1.FilterParameters.Add(new ControlParameter( DropDownList1.SelectedValue, "TextBox1", "Text" ));
    SqlDataSource1.FilterExpression = FilterExpression;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, @Asad. Thanks for posting the code, but please explain what the problem is.

Comment: when i filter data error show ()

Comment: Server Error in '/' Application.

Syntax error: Missing operand after ''%1%'' operator.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're just missing a space before the keyword `LIKE`:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string FilterExpression = string.Concat(DropDownList1.SelectedValue, " LIKE '%{0}%'"); 
    SqlDataSource1.FilterParameters.Clear();
    SqlDataSource1.FilterParameters.Add(new ControlParameter( DropDownList1.SelectedValue, "TextBox1", "Text" ));
    SqlDataSource1.FilterExpression = FilterExpression;
}
```

If your selected value is "BOB", your expression will result in BOBLIKE '%1%' instead of BOB LIKE '%1%'.

Also, depending on the content of your DropDownList and the context, you may need to quote that value.

Comment: its show error when i filter data 
Server Error in '/' Application. Syntax error: Missing operand after ''%1%'' operator

Comment: Here is the MS document about FilterExpression: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.110).aspx. According to this, a LIKE condition could use either `*` or '%' as wildcard character, which means that part of your expression is correct. The full expression should be in the form "ItemName LIKE '%product%'". If it is not working for you, please give us some information about what you expect the values of `DropDownList1.SelectedValue` and `TextBox1.Text` to be. Also, does DropDownList1 contain a list of field names?

Comment: i made a database and show database contain student information now i  want to add filter and show student information like department name , student name father name etc

Comment: <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
                    <asp:ListItem>ID</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Nationality</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Name</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>

Comment: i have these dropdownlist

Comment: i have user name father name nationality univeristy city date of birth ag no and department in my database

Comment: @Asad, please edit your question to include this information. Adding it as a series of comments makes it difficult for other users to understand the question fully.